# How can I use the Raspberry Pi as a Plex media server and access the files on my Firestick?

Tags: networking, media-server

everyone

The Raspberry Pi is an amazing machine, and there is a project I am aiming to do, but I need a bit of help.

I am aware that you can set up the RPi as a media server using Plex. However, I will have an external hard drive connected to the RPi with movies, home videos, etc.. that I want to watch on my Firestick.

How do I link my RPi to my Firestick, and also have access to all the files that the external hard drives have on them? i.e. going on my Firestick to watch a movie that is streamed from my RPi, on Plex, wirelessly.

I'm hoping to do this to get rid of the need of linking a laptop with a HDMI to my TV.

Thanks in advance

Comment: TBH not really a Pi issue.  Load VLC onto the Firestick, use SAMBA to share the drive mount point, use VLC to browse the 'local network' and select the file to play.

Comment: Install docker then run a plex container, use samba to share the drive, run plex on your FireTV. 
https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/plex
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-on-raspberry-pi
(install docker compose as well)